# Extract polygon names from external points: Extremely slow

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a text file including geolocation points.
I have a shapefile containing polygons and name of polygons. 
For each point, I have to extract the name of polygon if the polygon contains the point.
I tried as follows.
But it is extremely slow, it is taking me days....

```
import os, glob, numpy as np, pandas as pd, geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

fi = "polygons.shp"
gdf = gpd.read_file(fi)
print (gdf)        

fi = "points.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(fi, delimiter = ',')
print (df)

lons = df['Longitude']
lats = df['Latitude']

outputs = []

for lon, lat in list(zip(lons,lats)):
    point = Point(lon,lat)
    match = gdf[gdf.geometry.contains(point)].Name.astype(str)
    print (match)
    outputs.append([lon, lat, match])
outputs = np.array(outputs)
print (outputs.shape)
pd.DataFrame(outputs).to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I would suggest you to sjon your datasets first, which is really fast with geopandas see https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html and 
https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [Spatial Join](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html#geopandas.sjoin) with GeoPandas. If you wish you can subset the results to show only the points contained within your polygons using `notnull()`. This example performs a spatial join with 1,000,000 points and 10 polygons (i.e. A-J) in 42 seconds.

```
import geopandas as gpd

points_shp = '/path/to/points.shp'
polys_shp = '/path/to/polygons.shp'

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.read_file(points_shp))
polys = gpd.read_file(polys_shp)

# Spatial Join
join = gpd.sjoin(points, polys, how='left',op="within")

# Subset only values that do not contain nan
# "name" is field in the points that indicates which polygon it is contained within
subset = join[join['name'].notnull()]
```

---

[image]

[image]